# On Property Change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When a combo box with values 1-5  is changed at the front end, `onpropertychange` event fires a method that instantiates a `viewmodel` collection that reflects the value of the combo box. The combo box also handles some UI behaviour in the code behind when the selection is changed that handles showing and hiding some controls. The issue when the the value of the drop down is loaded from the database via the model the onproperty change event fires but it has no handler and is therefore ignored. Yet the code behind portion does fire and the correct controls are displayed on the screen. How can I make sure the this event is fired when the control value is changed by the data and not the user?

```
private void MethodInformationViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, 
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "NumberOfTests")
        {

            ManageRunDialogues();
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CB_NumberOfTests" Grid.Column="16" Grid.Row="4" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionChanged="CB_NumberOfTests_SelectionChanged" 
SelectedValue="{Binding 
vmcTPMViewModel.MethodInformationViewModel.NumberOfTests, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
                    </ComboBox>
```

I'm expecting any change of the property `NumberOfTests` to fire the `onpropertychenge` event. This is true but when the property changes when the database call populates the model in the model constructor, there is no handler and the change event does not fire and therefore the method call `ManageRunDialogues()` does not happen. What can I do ?

Comment: Relying on propertychanged seems inadvisable. Can't you drive this by property setter? Maybe your viewmodel would be easier to work with if it was flattened so number of tests is in the same class as properties it might logically have to manipulate. If that's impractical then maybe hand a reference to the parent viewmodel down.

Comment: Your viewmodel should be *fully functional* without *any* view attached. This is the MVVM rule. Implement your viewmodel in that way so it doesn't rely on view's code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late post. So the answer was to make sure the Model class instantiation happens after the `MethodInformationViewModel_PropertyChanged` event wire up has taken place. I had these the wrong way around so the properties had changed before the wireup in the `MethodInformationViewModel` and therefore caused this behaviour. Switching them meant that the listener worked as the model was being loaded from the DB.

To address the above, The number of tests is in the same class and the only thing being handled in the code behind is the UI.

I like the fact you can get voted down on a question, really encouraging guys! +1 for sarcasm?!? Thanks again for the scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM pattern do not use SelectionChanged event for any ViewModel change. Keep it only for the GUI changes if needed. (Ie. Background color, height, width ...)

All the ViewModel level changes on changing the selection can go to the setter of the NumberOfTests property.

```
private int _numberOfTests ;
public int NumberOfTests 
{
    get { return _numberOfTests; }
    set
    {
        _numberOfTests = value;
        pqr();   // Your extra operations that run when any one changes NumberOfTests
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

If you need to do extra operations before changing view model properties, (Only from back-end) I'd recommend to use an extra setter function.

```
public void UpdateNumberOfTests(int value)
{
    NumberOfTests = value;
    abc(); // Your extra operations that run only when back-end changes NumberOfTests.
}
```

Then let the back-end use that function. So your extra code will only get executed if the back-end changes NumberOfTests using UpdateNumberOfTests(int value).